# library not found for -lMMWormhole

Tags: ios, cordova, swift2, cocoapods

I got this error.

> ld: warning: directory not found for option
>   '-L/Users/span/Desktop/testbridge/platforms/ios/build/Debug-iphoneos'
>   ld: library not found for -lMMWormhole clang: error: linker command
>   failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: what command do you run, how do you see that error ?

Answer (score 0):

After run `pod install` or `pod update` you **must use** the **new** `.xcworkspace` file instead of the old `.xcodeproj` file.

It happens because `.xcworkspace` contains your `.xcodeproj` and the `pods`.

After that you should be able to run normally.